# Error: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm newbie in Spring Data.
I keep getting the error: `org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported`
I've tried to change consumes inside `@RequestMapping` annotation to `text/plain` but unfortunately it didn't help.*

Any ideas?

Thanks,

My Code looks like this:

```
package com.budget.processing.application;


import com.budget.business.service.Budget;
import com.budget.business.service.BudgetItem;
import com.budget.business.service.BudgetService;
import com.budget.processing.dto.BudgetDTO;
import com.budget.processing.dto.BudgetPerConsumerDTO;
import com.utils.Constants;
import com.common.utils.config.exception.GeneralException;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.joda.time.YearMonth;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;


@Controller("budgetManager")
@RequestMapping(value = "budget", produces  = Constants.RESPONSE_APP_JSON)
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class BudgetManager {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BudgetManager.class);


@Autowired
private BudgetService budgetService;


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public
@ResponseBody
Collection<BudgetDTO> getBudgetMonthlyAllConsumers() throws GeneralException {

    List<Budget> budgetList = budgetService.getBudgetForAllConsumers();
    List<BudgetDTO> bugetDtos = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Budget budget : budgetList) {
        BudgetDTO budgetDTO = generateBudgetDto(budget);
        bugetDtos.add(budgetDTO);
    }
    return bugetDtos;
}


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public
@ResponseBody
Collection<BudgetDTO> updateConsumerBudget(@RequestParam(value = "budgetPerDate", required = false)

                          ArrayList<BudgetPerConsumerDTO> budgetPerDate) throws GeneralException, ParseException {

    List<BudgetItem> budgetItemList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Budget> budgets = new ArrayList<>();
    if (budgetPerDate != null) {
        for (BudgetPerConsumerDTO budgetPerConsumerDTO : budgetPerDate) {
            budgetItemList.add(budgetService.createBudgetItemForConsumer(budgetPerConsumerDTO.getId(), new YearMonth(budgetPerConsumerDTO.getDate()), budgetPerConsumerDTO.getBudget()));
        }
    }

    budgets = budgetService.getBudgetForAllConsumers();
    List<BudgetDTO> budgetDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Budget budget : budgets) {
        BudgetDTO budgetDto = generateBudgetDto(budget);
        budgetDTOList.add(budgetDto);
    }
    return budgetDTOList;

}
```

}

Here is the exception I get:

```
ERROR 2014-07-26 18:05:10.737 (GlobalExceptionHandler.eITFMSException: 86) Error executing Web Service org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:289)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:229)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:298)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1091)
```

The request looks like that:
 i'm using Simple Rest Template Google Extension. the Request looks like the following:

```
localhost:8080/rest
1 requests ❘ 140 B transferred
HeadersPreviewResponseCookiesTiming
Remote Address:localhost:8080
Request URL: localhost:8080/rest/budget
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:331
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Cookie:JSESSIONID=AE87EEB7A73B9F9E81956231C1735814
Host:10.23.204.204:8080
Origin:chrome-extension://fhjcajmcbmldlhcimfajhfbgofnpcjmb
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
Request Payloadview parsed
{
"budgetPerDate":
[

         {
            "id":942,
            "date":[
               2014,
               1,
               1
            ],
    "budget": 100
         },
         {
            "id":942,
            "date":[
               2014,
               2,
               1
            ],
    "budget": 150
         }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Please give more of the stacktrace - at least enough to know in what class and method the exception occurs ...

Comment: I added some ot the stacktrace. let me know if there is a need for more

Comment: Show us what you send in your request, headers and body.

Comment: `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i've added the request. hope it's clear enough

Comment: @ankur-singhal in which spring version are you using? i don't have MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE . i'm using: Spring 3.2.2

Comment: You're using the wrong `MediaType` class, WS vs Spring's, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: From what I cat tell from the log of the HTTP  request you posted, you are using `Content-Type:text/plain`. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't make sense. You are sending JSON.

Comment: @geonal yeah i've notice that too, i'm using a different tool now for my Rest request (IntelliJ plugin ) and i don't get the following exception but the parameter: budgetPerDate is sending as null for some reason

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - I know, i switched to a different Rest plugin, sending the right Content-Type:application/json, and the parameter: budgetPerDate is passing as null

Comment: So what you actually want is to have your controller method use the JSON that is posted in the body?

Comment: @geonal, yes inside the request body

Comment: Content-type is wrong. It should mention that its JSON text.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Building on what is mentioned in the comments, the simplest solution would be:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public Collection<BudgetDTO> updateConsumerBudget(@RequestBody SomeDto someDto) throws GeneralException, ParseException {

    //whatever

}

class SomeDto {

   private List<WhateverBudgerPerDateDTO> budgetPerDate;


  //getters setters
}
```

The solution assumes that the HTTP request you are creating actually has

`Content-Type:application/json` instead of `text/plain`

Comment: It won't work if we can't change Content-Type for clients. how to support the Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' in Spring. Any help in that.

Comment: @jeevs it worked for me without any `consumes` annotation. Simply changed Postman content-type to 'JSON' instead of 'Text'

Comment: @tusar that is changing it on the 'client' side. jeevs is asking how to change it on the spring side assuing the clients are using the type "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"

Comment: @jeevs I had the same response error when submitting the request in Postman. Changed content-type to 'JSON' instead of 'Text'. It worked.

Answer (score 31):

Incase if you are giving a post request through `Postman` then make sure you have chosen these 2 options

**1.** **JSON (application/json)** should be chosen
[image]

**2. Content-Type** - application/json

[image]

Answer (score 20):

For me it turned out that I had a `@JsonManagedReferece` in one entity without a `@JsonBackReference` in the other referenced entity. This caused the marshaller to throw an error.

Comment: Had the same issue today, and it was pretty hard to figure out. Basically I just stepped my way through the debugger to find it. Even with log level set to trace the exception is just not logged. Very awkward exception handling at this part of Spring. Deserialization errors should never end up in a 415 status, rather a 400 or even 500...

Answer (score 1):

It works! Incase if you are giving a post request through Postman then make sure you have chosen these 2 options

https://arabicprogrammer.com/article/74621056167/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok - for me the source of the problem was in serialisation/deserialisation. The object that was being sent and received was as follows where the code is submitted and the code and maskedPhoneNumber is returned.

```
@ApiObject(description = "What the object is for.")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CodeVerification {

    @ApiObjectField(description = "The code which is to be verified.")
    @NotBlank(message = "mandatory")
    private final String code;

    @ApiObjectField(description = "The masked mobile phone number to which the code was verfied against.")
    private final String maskedMobileNumber;

    public codeVerification(@JsonProperty("code") String code, String maskedMobileNumber) {
        this.code = code;
        this.maskedMobileNumber = maskedMobileNumber;
    }

    public String getcode() {
        return code;
    }

    public String getMaskedMobileNumber() {
        return maskedMobileNumber;
    }
}
```

The problem was that I didn't have a JsonProperty defined for the maskedMobileNumber in the constructor. i.e. Constructor should have been

```
public codeVerification(@JsonProperty("code") String code, @JsonProperty("maskedMobileNumber") String maskedMobileNumber) {
    this.code = code;
    this.maskedMobileNumber = maskedMobileNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved by removed `@JsonManagedReference` and keep `@JsonBackReference`  as it  to avoid infinity loop .

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the value of the [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header in your request from `Content-Type: text/plain` to `Content-Type: application/json`.

In case you are using Postman for the POST request then make sure you have chosen this option (which will change the header value):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsWGH.png

Answer (score 0):

For anyone calling their Spring Backend from a ReactJS/Javascript frontend , you can add `header.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');` on your header. Basically, you do this:

```
const header = new Headers();
header.append('Content-Type', 'application/JSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`...

on `consumes` instead of `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` use `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`

Answer (score 0):

By default, [MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html)  supports application/json and application/*+json with UTF-8 character set. This can be overridden by setting the supportedMediaTypes property.
I add my converter and it works for me:

```
@Component
class MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterWithTextPlainSupport(objectMapper: ObjectMapper) :
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper) {
    init {
        supportedMediaTypes = supportedMediaTypes + MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN
    }
}
```